# how to print the sql in the procedure of mysql during a process?

Tags: mysql, procedure

I know that the function of print can print the sql sentence in sql server,I want to print the sql sentence of the procedure in mysql,the function of print is invalid.how can I print in mysql?

Comment: example of what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SHOW PROCEDURE CODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-procedure-code.html) command in mysql to view the procedure sql.

```
mysql> SHOW PROCEDURE CODE procedure_name
```

This will not show the actual query to create the **stored procedure**, but it will show the query (SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE/etc) present inside **stored procedure.**